# jquery not receiving the throw catch error but receive if enable setting in firebug

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug

I have this code for error

```
error: function(xhr) {alert(xhr.responseText); }
```

Now this is showing NuLL with normal setting

But if tick this setting 'Track throw cath error` then i see the full desciption of error in alert box otherwise it shows NULL

`I want to know is there any way to receive those error irrespective of firebug option`

[image]

EDIT:

I am using django so i was getting the exception . Error returned a full html page but NOne of alert box shows that unless i use the firebug option

The error is the Multi Object exception in Python djnago So that has less relevance

I am not using any try catch in JS

Comment: `console.log(xhr.responseText)`? or use the try function urself :)

Comment: If you're not using try/catch in any of your JavaScript code, then the Firebug setting probably doesn't have anything to do with this situation. It's just making it possible for you to see the XHR error content. What is the HTTP response code? What sort of error is it?

Comment: The error i get is from server side due to database exception but i want to see those errors so that i can see it. If i don't use ajax submit and submit normally then  after posting i go to exception page but i don't get any message if i submit via ajax

Answer (score 1):

First, this has nothing to do with jQuery.  The "throw/catch" error mechanism is a JavaScript thing. Second, this doesn't even look like it has anything to do with thrown exceptions; it looks like you're specifying an error handler for an XMLHttpRequest operation.

Finally, if there's an XHR error and you see a "null" in an alert, you *are* catching the exception, or handling the error or whatever. If you weren't you wouldn't see the alert at all. The problem is that you're expecting the "responseText" field of the XHR object to contain some error message apparently, and it doesn't.

You could try looking at "xhr.status" or "xhr.statusText".

Comment: I don't understand how can setting something in firebug console can chnage the output of my alert Box. I tried ur code `status=0` and `statusText = n/a`. i want those error message which i get by enabling `track throw catch`

Comment: You did not post exactly the error that you're getting, so it's hard to say what the issue is. You also did not post any code that uses either a "throw" statement or a "try/catch" block.

Comment: I have updated the question . I am submitting the form via `$(form).ajaxSubmit()`